# Sql where statement not working using asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

To better explain my problem with my personal website project, I would start off with the database that I have created. The table is called guitarItems. 
[image]

This table is where i get data for displaying images and guitar details in the webpage. In order to do this, I created a method named "GetGuitarItems" to execute and read the sql statements.

```
public static ArrayList GetGuitarItems(string itemCategory)
{
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM guitarItems WHERE brand LIKE '{0}'", itemCategory);

    try
    {
        conn1.Open();
        command1.CommandText = query;
        SqlDataReader reader = command1.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            string type = reader.GetString(1);
            string brand = reader.GetString(2);
            string model = reader.GetString(3);
            double price = reader.GetDouble(4);
            string itemimage1 = reader.GetString(5);
            string itemimage2 = reader.GetString(6);
            string description = reader.GetString(7);
            string necktype = reader.GetString(8);
            string body = reader.GetString(9);
            string fretboard = reader.GetString(10);
            string fret = reader.GetString(11);
            string bridge = reader.GetString(12);
            string neckpickup = reader.GetString(13);
            string bridgepickup = reader.GetString(14);
            string hardwarecolor = reader.GetString(15);

            GuitarItems gItems = new GuitarItems(id, type, brand, model, price, itemimage1, itemimage2, description, necktype, body,
                fretboard, fret, bridge, neckpickup, bridgepickup, hardwarecolor);
            list.Add(gItems);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        conn1.Close();
    }

    return list;
}
```

Next part is this code where you display the data that you have retrieved from the database.

```
public partial class Pages_GuitarItems1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private string brandType = "Ibanez";
private int x = 0;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillPage();
}

private void FillPage()
{
    ArrayList itemList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList itemListPage = new ArrayList();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        itemList = ConnectionClassGuitarItems.GetGuitarItems("%");
    }
    else
    {
        itemList = ConnectionClassGuitarItems.GetGuitarItems(brandType);
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (GuitarItems gList in itemList)
    {
        itemListPage.Add("GuitarItemsIbanezDetails" + (x + 1) + ".aspx");

        sb.Append(
                string.Format(
                    @"
                    <div class='one-two'>
                        <a href='{3}' runat='server'><img runat='server' src='{0}'/></a>
                        <div class='content'>
                            <div id='label'>{1} {2}</div>
                        </div>

                </div>", gList.ItemImage1, gList.Brand, gList.Model, itemListPage[x]));

        x++;

    }

    lblOutput.Text = sb.ToString();

}
}
```

Now the problem is its displaying every guitar items in the database. As shown from the code above, what I'm trying to display is only the guitar items with brand "Ibanez" in it. I have my suspicions with the foreach code but atleast for now, the GetGuitarItemsMethod is designed to get only the Ibanez guitar items and the data will be passed on to the ArrayList itemList variable for displaying. And I have also checked the sql statement and it seems correct. Hope you guys can help me on this one.

Comment: [Beware of little bobby tables.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Did you notice this line?
`itemList = ConnectionClassGuitarItems.GetGuitarItems("%");`

And use a parameterized query.

Comment: Just debug your code to check what are you getting from DB. Also I think you want `LIKE '%{0}%'  `

Comment: Try running the query generated by the code directly against the db in Sql Management Studio and see if that returns any result. If it does not, that mean the problem is with the query being generated in the code. You are missing '%' in the query when it is generated with itemCategory.

Comment: @aquinas - I removed the line of code that you said and it worked.

Comment: Also heed the other thing @aquinas pointed out: parameterize your query.  Never good to leave it like that.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Uhm does that mean i need to name my tables like "GT1" or something? Sorry still a beginner in sql.

Comment: No, it means you should use parameterized queries instead of concatenating strings for sql.

Comment: @MuqeetKhan - yes noted. Actually i have just researched about parameterized queries just now. Sql injections is nasty!

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Okay will do.

Comment: Did you test your query ?

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    itemList = ConnectionClassGuitarItems.GetGuitarItems("%");
}
else
{
    itemList = ConnectionClassGuitarItems.GetGuitarItems(brandType);
}
```

to

```
    itemList = ConnectionClassGuitarItems.GetGuitarItems(brandType);
```